# Converting infix to postfix using java

Tags: java, stack

this is my last resort. Will someone help me with my program?

The program is to convert infix to postfix, the issue is it won't give me an answer with decimal. I know i need to use double, but i don't know where to insert it.

here is my code

```
import java.util.*;  
class Stack   
{  
    int capacity = 10; 
    char arr []=new char[capacity];  
    int top = -1; 
    boolean isEmpty() 
    {  
        if(top==-1){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false; 
        }
    }  

    void push(char c)  
    {   
        top++; 
        if (top <= capacity-1)
        {  
            arr[top]= c; 
        }
        else if (top > capacity-1) 
        {  
            System.out.println("Overflow");  //Stack is ful
            System.exit(0);  
        }
    }

    char pop ()  
    {  
        if (isEmpty()==true){
            System.out.print("Underflow"); 
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return arr[top--]; 
    }    

    char peek() 
    {  
        return arr[top]; 
    }  
}  

public class Operations 
{  
    static Stack s = new Stack (); 

    static int precedence(char c){ 
        switch (c){
            case '+':
            case '-':
                return 1; 
            case '*':
            case '/':
                return 2;
            case '^':
                return 3; 
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static String Conversion(String val){ 

        String result = ""; 
        for (int i = 0; i <val.length() ; i++) {
            char c = val.charAt(i); 

          
            if(precedence(c)>0){
                while(s.isEmpty()==false && precedence(s.peek())>=precedence(c)){
                    result += s.pop(); 
                }
                s.push(c); 
            }else if(c==')'){
                char x = s.pop(); 
                while(x!='('){
                    result += x;
                    x = s.pop();
                }
            }else if(c=='('){
                s.push(c);
            }else{
                result += c; 
            }
            if (i+1 >= val.length() || !Character.isDigit(val.charAt(i+1)))
                result += ' '; 
        }
        while (!s.isEmpty())  
            result = result + s.pop(); 
        return result;
    }

    public static double Result(String Postfix)
    { 
        for(int i=0; i < Postfix.length(); i++) 
        { 
            char ch = Postfix.charAt(i); 

            //check if it is a space (separator)
            if(ch==' ')
                continue;

            if (Character.isDigit(ch)){ 
                double num = 0;

               
                while(Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                    num = num*10 + (ch-'0');
                    i++;
                    ch = Postfix.charAt(i);
                }
                i--;
               
                s.push((char)(num));
            }
            else       
            { 
                double value1 = s.pop(); 
                double value2 = s.pop(); 

                switch(ch) //evaluating the expression
                { 
                    case '+': 
                        s.push((char)(value2 + value1));
                        break; 

                    case '-': 
                        s.push((char)(value2 - value1)); 
                        break; 

                    case '*': 
                        s.push((char)(value2*value1)); 
                        break; 
                    case '/':  
                        if(value1==0){
                            System.out.print("Cannot divide by zero");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                        else
                            s.push((char)(value2/value1));
                        break; 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        return s.pop();   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Enter an infix expression: ");
        String val = sc.next(); 
        String Postfix = Conversion(val); 
        System.out.println("Postfix expression is: "+(Postfix.replaceAll("\\s+","")));
        System.out.println("Result of the evaluation is: " + Result(Postfix)); 

    }  
}
```

*i am not confident with the codes if it's correct. but any enlighten is welcome.
and perhaps can u help me with the loop? so i won't start to re-run the program everytime i input from the keyboard, big thanks seniors*

Comment: Can you post some examples of the Conversions you want to achieve.

Comment: like if i input an infix (1+2)*3/2 the result would be 4.5 but in my program's case it resulted to 4.0

Comment: I tried debugging your code but there's so many mistakes that you better start from scratch.
Bugs I've found: 
Replace whitespace before you call `Result`. 
"while (char.IsDigit)" Loop should be removed.
`double value1 = s.pop()` you're popping a char from the stack, which is not a double.
Don't mix chars and doubles on the stack. Or if you mix them convert them to the same number / char.